# how to check why is view controller being dismissed with no request

Tags: swift, xcode

I am implementing `UITableView` with `UISearchBar`, `TableViewController` being dismissed after calling below function :

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print ("in searchBarCancelButtonClicked")
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    self.resultSearchController.isActive = false
    self.tblview.reloadData()
    
}
```

I tried to debug the reasons behind this using `viewDidDisappear` and `viewWillDisappear` :

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    
    if self.isBeingDismissed{
        print("isBeingDismissed")
    }
    
    if self.isMovingToParent{
        print("isMovingToParent")
    }
    
    if self.isMovingFromParent{
        print("isMovingFromParent")
    }
    
    if self.isBeingPresented{
        print("isBeingPresented")
    }
    
    if self.isModalInPopover{
        print("isModalInPopover")
    }
}
```

and from debugger viewer nothing seem wearied:

> 2019-05-24 23:32:04.497835+0300 xx[38392:833231] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/mr3li/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BC644F58-4B75-4B77-B942-5A9FCD608F65/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
> 2019-05-24 23:32:04.499049+0300 xx[38392:833231] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.

Comment: What view controller do you think is being dismissed besides the search controller?

Comment: @rmaddy tableviewcontroller and goes back to previous viewcontroller

Comment: how can you combine tableView, and UISearchController, which contains its own tableView? Probably that's the one you see being dismissed when you do resultSearchController.isActive = false

Comment: please check the Storyboard hierarchy https://ibb.co/934CpB2

Comment: @DavidDavidoff you are totally right, resultSearchController.isActive = false dismissing the whole table view, now please tell me how to dismiss resultSearchController only when press cancel button please ?

Comment: @AliAlzahrani You dont't need UISearchController, if you have tableView and UISearchBar. You either only use UISearchController, or only tableView with a searchbar.

Comment: @DavidDavidoff please post your answer I will accept it. resultSearchController.isActive = false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced this code :

### self.resultSearchController.isActive = false

with this and worked fine for me :

### searchBar.endEditing(true)

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print ("in searchBarCancelButtonClicked")
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
    //self.resultSearchController.isActive = false
    searching = false
    self.tblview.reloadData()

}
```